# A finite-diameter Riemannian manifold with properly embedded infinite geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $S$ be the unit $2$-sphere minus the north and south poles, and let $M = (0,\pi) \times \mathbb R$. Define $q : M \to S$ by $q(\phi,\theta) = (\sin\phi\cos\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta, \cos\phi)$, and let $g$ be the metric on $M$ given by pulling back the round metric $g = q^*\mathring{g}$. Prove the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has diameter $\pi$, but contains infinitely long properly embedded geodesics.

Constructing the geodesics in question is simple: they are the preimages of great circles that do not pass through the north and south poles. The equator, for example, is one: $\gamma(t) = (\frac\pi 2, t)$ is a properly embedded geodesic in $M$ with infinite length. But this specific example seems to *disprove* the assertion that the diameter of $M$ is finite. What am I overlooking to show the diameter is finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That this problem illustrates that for some Riemannian manifolds $(M, g)$ the length-minimizing paths are not geodesics.

> **Example** (Up to reparameterization) the only geodesic that passes through $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{4})$ is the preimage of the the equator, that is, $t \mapsto (\frac{\pi}{2}, t)$, but the length of this geodesic between those two points is $\frac{5 \pi}{4}$, which (as the problem shows) is larger than the diameter $\pi$ of $M$, hence it is not length-minimizing.

(In fact, for this particular example there are pairs of points that are not connected by *any* geodesic, despite that the space is connected.) Indeed, this reinforces the point that geodesics are *locally* length-minimizing, but globally they need not be. (There are simpler examples of this fact, too: For any nonantipodal points $x, y \in S^n$, the minor and major arcs of the great circle passing through them are both geodesics, but the major arc is longer than the minor arc and hence not minimizing.)

**Hint** The key observation is that the metric in the preimage of the polar regions is small, so a strategy for building a short path between two points is to travel from your starting point to that region, do your lateral movement there, and then drop down to the point of interest.

> **Additional hint** Suppose we want to travel from $(a, b)$ to $(a', b')$. Then we have at least one of $a + a' \leq \pi$ or $(\pi - a) + (\pi - a') \leq \pi$, and by symmetry (reflection $M$ across the preimage of the equator) we may as well assume the former. Consider the path $\gamma_\epsilon$ defined to be the concatenation of the paths $\gamma_\epsilon^1$ connecting $(a, b)$ vertically (along a "meridian") from to $(\epsilon, b)$ where $0 < \epsilon \leq \min\{a, a'\}$, $\gamma_\epsilon^2$ connecting $(\epsilon, b)$ horizontally (along a "parallel") to $(\epsilon, b')$, and $\gamma_\epsilon^3$ connecting $(\epsilon, b')$ to $(a', b')$ vertically. Then, length of $\gamma$ satisfies \begin{align}L(\gamma_\epsilon) &= L(\gamma_1) + L(\gamma_2) + L(\gamma_3)\\ &= (a - \epsilon) + |b' - b| \sin \epsilon + (a' - \epsilon)\\ &\leq (a + a') + (|b' - b| - 2) \epsilon \leq \pi + (|b' - b| - 2) .\epsilon\end{align} So, the distance from $(a, b)$ to $(a', b')$ satsfies$$d((a, b), (a', b')) = \inf_\gamma L(\gamma) \leq \inf_{\epsilon > 0} L(\gamma_\epsilon) \leq \pi ,$$ where in the second expression $\gamma$ varies over all curves from $(a, b)$ to $(a', b')$. But those points were arbitrary, so $$\operatorname{diam}(M, d) = \sup d((a, b), (a', b')) \leq \pi ,$$ where the supremum is taken over $M \times M$. To show equality, by definition we need to produce sequences $(a_i, b_i)$ and $(a_i', b_i')$ such that $$\sup_i d((a_i, b_i), (a_i', b_i')) = \pi .$$ Of course, it would suffice to find points $(a, b), (a', b')$ such that $d((a, b), (a', b')) = \pi$. One such pair is $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I think there's something fundamental I'm missing about this example in particular. What about the points $x = (\frac \pi 2, 0)$ and $y = (\frac\pi 2, 2k\pi)$ for $k \geq 1$ ? It's hard for me to see a path connecting these points in $M$ that has length $\leq \pi$.

Comment: Oh, I misread the problem statement as specifying a parameterization, whereas $M \to S$ is actually a Riemannian covering map. The claim is still true I think, but the argument is more subtle. The key point is that horizontal lines in the preimages of the polar regions are relatively short, so the strategy should be the build a path from the starting point, head toward one pole or the other, move laterally, and then drop down to the end point. I'll rewrite my answer when I get home.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I eventually figured out. You move to either the north or south pole along a line of latitude, and then wrap around the pole a sufficient number of times in a sufficiently small (non-geodesic) circle, before going to the second point along a line of latitude. The resulting paths may or may not have length $\pi$, and in fact may have length strictly greater than $\pi$, but as that wrapping circle gets small, the paths approach something $\leq \pi$.

Comment: Actually I really like this example! It's an incomplete Riemannian manifold, some of whose points cannot be connected by length-minimizing geodesics. Counter-intuitive, but very cool :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right---for the benefit of anyone who comes to this problem later, I've rewritten my answer to include some of the relevant computations.

Comment: And it's definitely a nice example. A simpler example with the same property is $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$, equipped with the restriction of the Euclidean metric. In that case, too, not only are there points that cannot be connected by a geodesic, there are points for which there is no length-minimizing curve connecting them.